# How can I send an email to a user when a post in their category changes

Tags: email

I am trying to send an email to my students when I create a new exercise for them.
I create a category that has the same name as the user [student]. Then when I create a new exercise/assignment I simply assign it to a category.
[see master page=> https://www.wlc-idiomas.com/homework-willie]

The question/problem is that I want to send an email to the student each time I assign a new exercise for them to do. I have seen lots of plugins and some codes, but they can't seem to help with my particular problem. Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "their" category? Do you mean if users have authored a post in category XYZ then all authors of posts with the same category get notified by email?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a plugin like [Better Notifications for WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/).  There are a couple, but this one is free, and the video makes it seem really easy to implement.